# RobotFramework : raise PassExecution does not work

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

We are using RobotFramework for our automation. In one of our python module we want to pass the test status using PASS Execution inside the python code.

I tried using raise PassExecution but all I get is a message but the test case continues without stopping. Also I tried calling the keyword pass_execution but seeing the same behaviour.

Can anyone let me know how to acheive it?

Here is my code

```
def fetchData(productType , attributes=[]):
    result_Array = fetch_url_response(productType , attributes)
    iterator = 1
    data_List = list()
    while(iterator < len(result_Array)):
        try:
            data_List.append((result_Array[iterator])[1:11])
            iterator = iterator + 1
        except Exception as ex:
            print ex
        # Shuffles the List of data
    random.shuffle(data_List) 
    print "Checking the data Length."
    if len(data_List) < 1:
        print "Length less than 1. Pass the Execution"
        #call_keyword('pass_execution' , 'No data found for the criteria. Passing the test case')
        raise PassExecution('No data found for the criteria. Passing the test case')
    else:
        data = data_List[0]
        return data
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code it's impossible to know what you're doing wrong.

There are two ways for a keyword to cause the test to immediately stop with a PASS status: raise a `robot.errors.PassExecution` exception, or call the built-in keyword `pass_execution`.

Here's an example of two keywords using each method:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
from robot.errors import PassExecution

def custom_keyword_1():
    BuiltIn().pass_execution("life is good")

def custom_keyword_2():
    raise PassExecption("life is still good")
```

To test it, save it to a file called `custom_keywords.py', and use it like this:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | custom_keywords.py

*** Test cases ***
| Example 1
| | log | before calling the custom keyword
| | custom keyword 1
| | log | after calling the custom keyword

| Example 2
| | log | before calling the custom keyword
| | custom keyword 2
| | log | after calling the custom keyword
```

When you run the above, you should see the first log message and the "life is good" message, but you won't see the final log message in each test since the test immediately finishes with a "pass" status.

Comment: Actually I had the same code you had mentioned. In the Output I can see the message sent to PassExecution but the test continued instead of stopping.

Comment: @Shari: so, with the exact code above, you're saying that you're seeing the "after calling..." log message in each test?

Comment: Yes, I am seeing the "After calling..." message in the console after the message "life is good"...

Comment: What version of robot are you using? This should work. Do your logs show any other errors or warnings?

Comment: I am using 2.8(the latest one). No other warnings apart from other keywords running and throwing error.

Comment: @Shari: have you considered that maybe it's some of those other errors that are contributing to this problem? Also, I was asking about the logs when you run the code in my answer -- you're saying my answer doesn't work, are there _any_ errors or warnings? I'm confused when you say "other keywords", because my answer doesn't call any other keywords.

Comment: So found the issue. The block calling the above code was wrapped in try / catch which was eating up the exception. Removing it made the code work fine.